# Adding audio to my page

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I am trying to add audio to my page. The thing is I have a lightbox in it, and once I click the lightbox the sounds come out.

This is my javascript:

```
audio = $("audio").get(0)

$('a').click(function(){
    if(audio.paused){
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.pause();
    }
});
```

​This is my HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <img src="img/speaker_icon.png" alt="play" />
</a>
<audio>
    <source src="sound/siol.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="sound/siol.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>​
```

Any idea what should I change? Any quick fix?

Comment: Check my answer on a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634862/adding-sound-on-clicking-a-image-in-html-5/12635093#12635093.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below working code for resolution.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function playerClicked() {
     audio=$("audio").get(0);
     audio.load()
       if(audio.paused){
        audio.play();
       } else {
        audio.pause();
       }

    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a id ="storyplayer" href="javascript:playerClicked();">
Click here to play.
</a>
<audio>
<source src="sound/siol.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update my previous answer with jquery code:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <img src="http://www.kafkabrigade.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/button-pic.jpg" alt="play" />
</a>
<audio>
    <source src="http://www.hellopixel.net/click.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="http://www.hellopixel.net/click.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

jQuery:

```
audio = $("audio").get(0)

$('a').click(function(){
    if(audio.paused){
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.pause();
    }
});
```

And here is the working js fiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/SMR4V/1/
​
​

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily put controls on for audio to check if the element appears there and is usable manually, use your browser's developer tools for debugging.
At first glance I'd say it's the missing ; from the end of the first line, it should be:

```
audio = $("audio").get(0);
```