# Assign sounds to element with drag drop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a interesting idea(debatable). Basically I would like to make a beat pad similar to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vC5TsSyNjU out of jQuery and a keyboard.

It wasn’t hard assigning sounds to keys on the keyboard.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.playSound.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery(document).bind(
            'keydown', 
            'q',
            function(ect){
                $.playSound('tracks/basses/bass01.ogg');
            });

        jQuery(document).bind(
            'keydown', 
            'w',
            function(ect){
                $.playSound('tracks/drums/clap04.ogg');
            });         

        jQuery(document).bind(
            'keydown', 
            'e',
            function(ect){
                $.playSound('tracks/beats/rave_hihat02.ogg');
            });

        jQuery(document).bind(
            'keydown', 
            'r',
            function(ect){
                $.playSound('tracks/4.wav');
            });


}); // End
</script>
```

How can I drag/drop sounds to a key on the keyboard?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by : "How can I drag/drop sounds to a key on the keyboard?"

Comment: If I had a virtual keyboard made from css and html on my webpage and a directory of sounds, how can I drag the sound to a key. So when I push the key on my keyboard it will play the sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>hello</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
<style>

.key{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

.song{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 1px #f0f;
    float: right;
}

</style>
<script src=""></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


    $( ".song" ).draggable();

    $( ".key" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
        var title = ui.draggable.attr('title');
                $(this).attr({
                    //text: 'Beijing Brush Seller',
                    title: title,
                });
                    //alert("Dropped!");
        }
    });

    $(this).bind(
        'keydown', 
        'q',
        function(ect){
            var track = $('.key').attr("title");
            //alert(track);
            var snd = new Audio(track); // buffers automatically when created
            snd.play();
    });

    $(this).bind(
        'keydown', 
        'w',
        function(ect){
            var track = $('.key').attr("title");
            //alert(track);
            var snd = new Audio(track); // buffers automatically when created
            snd.play();
    });

    $(this).bind(
        'keydown', 
        'a',
        function(ect){
            var track = $('.key').attr("title");
            //alert(track);
            var snd = new Audio(track); // buffers automatically when created
            snd.play();
    });

}); // End
</script>

<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="key" title="">Key</div>

<div class="song" id="" title="tracks/basses/bass01.ogg">Song</div>
<div class="song" id="" title="tracks/bassloopes/rave_bass01.ogg">Song</div>
<div class="song" id="" title="tracks/basses/synth_acid02.ogg">Song</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i understand your question. Here is the way i would proceed:

```
function drawImage(e) {    
    e = e || window.event;   

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {           
       if (counter < images.length) {            
            counter ++;

           if(playable) {
               audio.src = sounds[counter-1];
               audio.controls = false;
               audio.load();
               audio.play();
           }

           var img = new Image();
           img.src = images[counter-1];
           img.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT); 

           }
      }
    }
}
```

First of all you need to assign for each key pressed an audio file stored into an array. You can create the audios from html markup, but this way is more elegant. So i will stick with this way. Then for each key press associate an audio from the corresponding audio array. In my example i used canvas for associating an image to an audio file. This is however only for visual appearance. Note that for simplicity i only used the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. For each key press you will hear another beep.

Another thing which you have to take into account is to use test cases because not every browser can play audio. You can test if the browser support audio like so:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
var canPlay = !!(audio.canPlayType && audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;').replace(/no/, ''));
var playable = canPlay ? true : false;
```

If not you can use fallback to flash: 
[Adding sound on clicking a image in HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634862/adding-sound-on-clicking-a-image-in-html-5/12635093#12635093)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/N9Q6S/1/